# Is there a way to add data from my mongodb into my html file

Tags: html, node.js

I have been trying all i could and nothing seems to work. Is there a way i could request for all the data in a collection in mongo db into my html code.

E.g
I have a products database with schemas;
Name
Price
Image
Description.

So i want to ensure that everything in this particular database get deployed into my html page automatically.
I hope you understand me.

Comment: Please describe your previous attempts in detail, including the ways in which they failed (with exact error messages, if any).

Comment: I tried to insert it using ejs as a view engine, it worked, but what i actually want is for it to automatically find all products in my database and include it into my html

Comment: I don't understand what you mean - it sounds like you already found the correct solution. What do you mean by your last sentence? As you already said yourself, you can use EJS to render the data at the appropriate points inside your HTML.

Comment: I mean how to make sure every data in my database be automatically uploaded into my html.

Comment: Sorry it still doesn't quite make sense. Every time someone opens your page, your backend code will run and fetch the latest data, and your EJS code will render it. So it is inherently up-to-date anyway. What is missing?

Comment: Yea...exactly you got it.

Comment: The question is how to make it run and fetch the latest data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219148/discussion-between-ogunrinade-gbolahan-and-cherrydt).